# canvas.drawText() is not showing up in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write text to the screen using a new method taking in all of the arguments needed to draw the text. The only text showing up is the text being centered and showing up directly in the middle.

Example:

```
//create texts
    writeText(canvas, "Money: $" + player.getMoney(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 25, (screenWidth / 2), 50);
    writeText(canvas, "MPS: " + player.getMPS(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 25, (screenWidth / 2), 75);
    writeText(canvas, "MPC: " + player.getMPC(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 25, (screenWidth / 2), 100);
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getHouseUpgradeCost(), Paint.Align.RIGHT, Color.BLACK, 15, 0, (screenHeight - buttonHeight));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getConstructionWorkerCost(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 15, (screenWidth / 2), (screenHeight - buttonHeight));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getBobCost(), Paint.Align.LEFT, Color.BLACK, 15, screenWidth, (screenHeight - buttonHeight));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getWorkGroupCost(), Paint.Align.RIGHT, Color.BLACK, 15, 0, ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 3))));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getBankCost(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 15, (screenWidth / 2), ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 3))));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getFactoryCost(), Paint.Align.LEFT, Color.BLACK, 15, (screenWidth), ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 3))));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getSuperTappingCost(), Paint.Align.RIGHT, Color.BLACK, 15, 0, ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 5))));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getUnlockStoreCost(), Paint.Align.CENTER, Color.BLACK, 15, (screenWidth / 2), ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 5))));
    writeText(canvas, "Cost: $" + player.getPropertyCost(), Paint.Align.LEFT, Color.BLACK, 15, (screenWidth), ((screenHeight - (buttonHeight * 5))));
}

private void writeText(Canvas canvas, String text, Paint.Align align, int color, int textSize, float x, float y) {
    //Sets paint using values
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(align);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);

    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
}
```

Comment: and it is not showing up where? are you applying the canvas?

Comment: Yes, everything is showing up except for the text not centered to the middle. all others do not show up.